# Select Menu fails to update with Javascript in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jsf

I am using this select one menu on my website to determine the number of results on the page.  However, when I change my selection, it does nothing.  I was wondering if it was something in my onchange statement that was broken or if there could be another cause?

I have tried changing value to getAttribute('value') and couldn't get that to work either.  Also, I can't get my Chrome debugger to set a breakpoint there so I can step through.  If anyone can help on any of these fronts that would be most helpful.  Thanks.

```
    <select size="1" id="pageSize" onchange="document.frmDisplay.pageSize.value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value" style="font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 10px;z-index: 99">
             <option value="10">10</option>
             <option value="20" style="" selected="">20</option>
             <option value="50">50</option>
             <option value="100">100</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `name` attribute to your select list.  The form elements collection indexes members by name (not ID)

```
<select size="1" name="pageSize" id="pageSize" onchange="document.frmDisplay.pageSize.value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value" style="font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 10px;z-index: 99">
         <option value="10">10</option>
         <option value="20" style="" selected="">20</option>
         <option value="50">50</option>
         <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

you can still keep the `id` attribute of course.

actually looking at your code... you are attempting to set the field to its own value... which makes no sense... what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Changing the page size.  I'm trying to change 12 year old code to work with Chrome.  The code itself doesn't make much sense to me either, most of its broken up in XSL.

Comment: should the form be submitting itself somehow?... right now the above onchange even doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: Theres a refresh button to submit the change.  I added the name but seems to cause it to not load that part.  Adding the name and rebuilding.  No change in result.

Comment: From my understanding "this.options[this.selectedIndex].value" should be the value selected by the user and "document.frmDisplay.pageSize.value" should be the value of the pageSize that is currently being displayed.  There is a submit button that when hit, should do that, right?  Or that's at least how it worked (even if not properly)in IE. Do you think I need to grab the attribute for the value?

Comment: ah, wait... is "frmDisplay" the name of the form that this select list is contained in?  If so, this JavaScript does nothing but set the select's value to what you just picked. (e.g. moot)  if however "frmDisplay" is some other element... this *might* do something but it is very hard to tell.  Can you post more sample code or link to the full page?

Comment: sorry for the delay.  Heres a link to the code, I can't link the site itself.  Line 519 is what we are looking at.  Thanks a lot. [http://www.docdroid.net/2rlk/templatefc.txt.html](http://www.docdroid.net/2rlk/templatefc.txt.html)

Comment: The form name is on line 482, it is frmDisplay. @scunliffe

Comment: I can only guess that the code is trying to take the selected value from the select list and put it into a hidden field.  However since BOTH elements have the **same name** trying to reference them from the "form collection" will be confusing (the browser doesn't know which one you want). If I suspect correctly that you are trying to populate the hidden field, the best thing to do would be to rename the select list to avoid the name conflict.